# Do i have to cast an already generic array in java to a generic type

Tags: java, list, generics, data-structures, annotations

Sorry for the wording but maybe code can be understood easier

```
public class Generic<E> implements List<E>
{
    private static final int defaultSize = 10; //Default size
    private int maxSize; //Maximum size of list
    private int listSize; //Current # of items in list
    private int curr; //Position of current element
    private E[] listArray; //Array holding list elements
    Generic()
    {
        this(defaultSize);
    }
    /**
    * Create a new list object
    * @param siz Max # of elements list can contain
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //generic array allocation
    Generic(int size)
    {
        maxSize = size;
        listSize = curr = 0;
        listArray = (E[]) new Object[size]; //create listArray
```

My two questions are these:

1. The last line, when I create the list as an object of size `size`, why do I have to cast it as a generic array when it's initialized as a generic array already?
2. Can the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked");` be explained? What it does I can see, but I have never seen the `@SuppressWarnings` on any of the pages in my Java book; how can we start with `@`??

Sidenote - this code is straight from my Data Structures book and I'm trying to break it down to understand it.

Comment: Arrays aren't generic, and at run-time (due to type erasure) every generic is of type `Object`.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings` is an [annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/). They were introduced in version 1.5, any recent book should mention them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to recast it as `E[]` because of [*type erasure*](https://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html): at runtime, every generic is treated as `Object`. You can't initialize `listArray` as `new E[]`.
2. `@SuppressWarnings` is an annotation, basically extra information besides imperative code.

You have to supressed `unchecked` because otherwise the Java compiler will warn you when it encounters the potentially dangerous cast of `Object[]` to `E[]`.